# How do I make the same Facebook object available to all my code in my iOS Facebook SDK project?

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk, ios

I've tried passing in the Facebook object which I named `facebook` as an argument into classes that rely on it. However, is there a way to use it in a sort of global way so that way I don't have to keep on passing it around between objects?

Comment: it would be best to mark a question as the answer or add more details if the answers provided are not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I see several ways:

- Create a public static method in a class that contains facebook object:

  ```
  + (id)getSharedFacebookObject {
      return facebook;
  }
  ```
- The second way is to use app delegate:

  ```
  MyAppDelegate *appDel = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  id Facebook = appDel.facebook;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use the singleton pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Create a new class that has the facebook object as an instance variable and set the new class as the facebook delegate. You can then get the sharedInstance from any class and it will return the same object.

This may not actually be the correct solution to your problem. It may require you to add another layer of communication between the singleton and the particular view controller you are using. If you are only performing simple functions then this may be fine.